# Solr query syntax with if, exists and query functions

Tags: solr

[The Solr function query documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#exists) says:

exists(query({!v='year:2012'})) will return true for docs with year=2012

I have a document like:

```
  {
    "prod_refExt": [
      "1.37.816-nr¤|¤100666¤|¤123596¤|¤5.134.06"
    ],
    "prod_oid": "21956",
    "prod_label": "COIN",
    "prod_refBrand": [
      "1.37.816-nr;;NOREMAT¤|¤100666;;REMPLACEMENT¤|¤123596;;NOREMAT¤|¤5.134.06;;ROUSSEAU"
    ],
    "prod_xrmCategory": [
      "0001007b"
    ],
    "prod_code": "123596"
  }
```

prod_refBrand is a multivalued field, what I want to do is :
If I have in one of the docs returned "100666;;REMPLACEMENT" as a exact match from prod_refBrand I should have only this doc.

I issue a query like this but it doesn't do what I want when "if" returns a false value

```
q=prod_refBrand:if(exists(query({!v="prod_refBrand:100666;;REMPLACEMENT"})),"100666;;REMPLACEMENT",*)
```

How do I fix the query?

Comment: What do you want the query to do when if returns false? Return all docs where prod_refBrand has a value?

Comment: if returns false, it should return prod_refBrand:*

Comment: OK. I've always used field:[* TO *] to find documents with a field so if that's what you were trying to achieve..

Comment: That doesn't work neither.
I tried to do that :
q=prod_refBrand:if(exists(query({!v="prod_refBrand:100666;;REMPLACEMENT"})),"100666;;REMPLACEMENT",[* TO *])

Comment: So your query is: If a match is guaranteed, return it, otherwise, return all documents that have any value in this field. right?

Is this the full query or do you combine it with other queries?

Comment: Yes exactly @mjalajel , I will combine it with this : prod_label:"100666" OR prod_label:*100666* OR prod_label:100666* OR prod_label:*100666 OR prod_label:100666 OR prod_refExt:"100666"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't think you can achieve that in a single query. You see, most (if not all) the functions work per document (include exists and query), so this will return true for the first document and false for others (different results per document). You cannot change the query itself using this method.

The obvious solution is to issue two queries: first check for exact matches and if nothing is found, re-query with the full results.